# Adding ASP.NET Server Side Controls Dynamically Like as Javascript

Tags: html, asp.net, dynamic

I have a simple aspx page.

In this page I want to add dynamically dropdownlist-textbox pairs that represent key-value pairs. But I dont know how much it is when page loading. 
So I must add these controls to page dynamically(in runtime)

If I add these controls in codebehind 2 problems arise :

- Page is reloaded in every appending because of autopostback. It couses blink.
- Whenever page reloads, previous appending disappear.

If I add these controls in client-side(javascript) :

- Controls cannot be reachable in codebehind(because no runat=server) so validation steps open to user(I think validation steps must operate in codebehind othervise this is an integrity problem).

What would be true approach about this problem ? Could give example ?

Answer (score 1):

If you want to avoid the blink(page reload) you have to go for adding the control dynamically into your form using JavaScript.

> Controls cannot be reachable in codebehind(because no runat=server)

This statement is not correct, you can always access your form control at server side using `Request.Form` collection. Check [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms525985(v=vs.90).aspx) for more details. You will be required to iterate over the contents of this collection to get the values.

> I think validation steps must operate in codebehind othervise this is
>   an integrity problem

Validation you need to do by yourself before performing any operation. You might required to write some custom validation logic.